# yammer oauth error invalid redirect uri

Tags: oauth-2.0, yammer

We integrate with YAMMER using OAuth2.0 Server-side flow.

Some of our clients have subdomains so our redirect URI has to be dynamic. We set up the yammer-app to have a dynamic redirect URI as specified in the [documentation](http://developer.yammer.com/introduction/#gs-registerapp). Our redirect URI looks like this:

```
https://example.com
```

Problem:

It works not every time! Some redirects to the YAMMER user authentication page are getting this error:

```
invalid redirect_uri
```

The URL looks like this:

```
https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=http://www.examle.com/yammer/callback
```

The error only happens some times so it is hard to reproduce or trace the reason.

I tried to remove the redirect url form the app setup on YAMMER. The error still occurs!

Does anybody encountered this problem as well?
What could we do wrong?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. According to the documentation my first approach was correct. To use a dynamic redirect URL input the domain like this: 
`https://example.com`

Comment: I have just had this issue. See my answer as it may also explain why it was happening some times and not others. In my case, I was visiting the 'http' version of my url and not the 'https'. For some reason the source http is overriding the redirect uri that I have specified in my Yammer Created Apps page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to redirect to the default (http://yammer.com/). In the past you didn't need this parameter and it would always redirect to http://yammer.com.

See these out-dated docs:
https://developer.yammer.com/oauth2-quickstart/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't understand, why should I redirect to yammer? I want yammer to redirect to my domain.